# Using scripts in python for libraries that aren't installed?

Tags: python

I'm very very new to Python, but I'm curious. I'm currently writing an automation script for some people and I'm using the XLRD library. If I send this script to someone and they try and run it on their computer, clearly there will be some import issues. What is the best way to resolve this? I know in Django, I would make some sort of requirements.txt file, but unsure how this works and how they would get the downloaded libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I've never used XLRD and don't know what it is, but you could do something like:

```
try:
    import XLRD
except ImportError:
    XLRD=None
```

and then whenever you need to use XLRD, you can have an if block, like:

```
if XLRD:
    do what you're supposed to do
else:
    do something similar that doesn't require XLRD
```

It would also be possible to do something else in that except ImportError block, such as print a warning with instructions on how to obtain XLRD. If the person has pip installed, you might even be able to access the command line and run pip to download XLRD, but if they don't have that either, then you're back with the same ImportError.